# Help with JSON raw format in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON array of data which is

```
[ [[2, 5], [6, 10], [10, 7], [11, 15]],
  [[0, 9], [1, 16], [3, 19], [4,  15]],
  [[0, 7], [5, 16], [8, 17], [12, 19]] ]
```

but when I try to get the first array of `[[2, 5], [6, 10], [10, 7], [11, 15]]` using `jsonData[0]` I get the data as `2,5,6,10,10,7,11,15`.

I would like to get the data in the JSON format and not the plain text format. Any ideas?

Comment: I get what you'd expect using identical syntax, perhaps show us a bit more...the problem must be further along in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to convert it to a JSON string rather than simply getting the default toString behaviour of an array?  If so you should just do:

```
JSON.stringify(jsonData[0])
```

Or whatever it is you want to stringify

Answer (score 3):

You should get the data as an array. Did you alert `jsonData[0]` because that will display the results as a flattened string.

Instead `console.log(jsonData[0])` to see the actual array.

Here's the output I see when using your array.

```
var a = [[[2, 5], [6, 10], [10, 7], [11, 15]],[[0, 9], [1, 16], [3, 19], [4, 15]],[[0, 7], [5, 16], [8, 17], [12, 19]]];

alert(a[0]);       // 2,5,6,10,10,7,11,15

console.log(a[0]); // [[2, 5], [6, 10], [10, 7], [11, 15]]
```

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gWTzs/).

Also, "JSON raw format" is misleading. What you have is a plain JavaScript array.